# Why DISTINCT keyword lead to different entity for these two queries?

Tags: sparql, freebase

Query 1

```
PREFIX ns: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>
SELECT DISTINCT ?x
WHERE {
FILTER (!isLiteral(?x) OR lang(?x) = '' OR langMatches(lang(?x), 'en'))
?x ns:type.object.type ns:religion.religious_leadership_title .
?x ns:religion.religious_leadership_title.leaders ?c0 .
?c0 ns:religion.religious_organization_leadership.start_date ?sk0 .
}
ORDER BY ?sk0
LIMIT 1
```

Query 2

```
PREFIX ns: <http://rdf.freebase.com/ns/>
SELECT ?x
WHERE {
FILTER (!isLiteral(?x) OR lang(?x) = '' OR langMatches(lang(?x), 'en'))
?x ns:type.object.type ns:religion.religious_leadership_title .
?x ns:religion.religious_leadership_title.leaders ?c0 .
?c0 ns:religion.religious_organization_leadership.start_date ?sk0 .
}
ORDER BY ?sk0
LIMIT 1
```

So the only difference between Q1 and Q2 is that there is a `DISTINCT` keyword when `SELECT ?x` in Q1. However, Q1 gives answer `m.01h_90` while Q2 gives answer `m.05rd8`.
Ideally, I feel this should not lead to different results, as the purpose of `DISTINCT` is only to get rid of duplicates in the results set if I understand it correctly, so if the original results do not have duplicates at all, there should not be any difference by adding the `DISTINCT` keyword.

Comment: You must have a tie in the value you're ordering. Specifying `distinct` is causing a different plan which orders the rows differently. Add that column to the `order by` and see if it's consistent.

Comment: @shawnt00 exactly. I tried `SELECT DISTINCT ?x, ?sk0` and `SELECT ?x, ?sk0`, and they are consistent, which makes me confused

Comment: @shawnt00 could you make it more elaborate by posting an answer? Then I can accept your answer. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a tie on the value you're ordering. Specifying `distinct` is causing a different execution plan which orders the rows differently, though still ordering by the one column as requested, with another row as the first one to output. Add the output column to the `order by` clause and you should see consustent results between the two queries.